# Android only attempts to fetch location after 90 seconds

Tags: android, gps, android-source

I have some problems with GPS/Location on a custom Android device we are developing. Generally, GPS is pretty quick, but the first time I request a location after boot, it takes about 90 seconds to get a fix. I thought first this is a problem with AGPS, however it seems that it is working properly.

Here is an excerpt from logcat. I start an app that requests GPS at 15:37:02. Not much happens, and pretty much exactly 90 seconds later I get a lot of activity.

I added some further debug statements not visible here, and what seems to be happening is that only after 90 seconds, Android attempts to get the time via NTP, and then attempts to do AGPS, and within seconds I get a fix. Note that this device currently does not have a SIM card inserted. Does anybody have an idea what could cause this kind of behavior? I assume the reason Android waits is that it will first try other sources of location before GPS for power saving reasons, however this is no concern for me since the device is not battery powered.

```
# logcat | grep -Ei '(gps|locatio)'
...
02-21 15:36:49.362  2555  4381 I ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.chartcross.gpstest/.GPSTest (has extras)} from uid 10009 on display 0
02-21 15:36:49.436  2555  2763 I ActivityManager: Start proc 5898:com.chartcross.gpstest/u0a27 for activity com.chartcross.gpstest/.GPSTest
...
02-21 15:37:00.806  4736  5100 I GCoreUlr: Starting service, intent=Intent { act=com.google.android.location.reporting.ACTION_UPDATE_WORLD cmp=com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.location.reporting.service.DispatchingService (has extras) }, extras=Bundle[{receiverAction=init, is_boot=true}]
02-21 15:37:00.976  4736  5126 I GCoreUlr: WorldUpdater received intent Intent { act=com.google.android.location.reporting.ACTION_UPDATE_WORLD cmp=com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.location.reporting.service.DispatchingService (has extras) } with receiverAction com.google.android.location.internal.server.ACTION_RESTARTED
02-21 15:37:01.260  4736  5126 I GCoreUlr: WorldUpdater:com.google.android.location.internal.server.ACTION_RESTARTED: Ensuring that reporting is stopped because of reasons: (no Google accounts)
02-21 15:37:01.904  4736  5126 I GCoreUlr: WorldUpdater received intent Intent { act=com.google.android.location.reporting.ACTION_UPDATE_WORLD cmp=com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.location.reporting.service.DispatchingService (has extras) } with receiverAction init
02-21 15:37:02.661  2555  4381 I ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.chartcross.gpstest/.GPSTest (has extras)} from uid 10009 on display 0
02-21 15:37:02.714  2555  6671 I ActivityManager: Start proc 7164:com.chartcross.gpstest/u0a27 for activity com.chartcross.gpstest/.GPSTest
...
02-21 15:38:32.349  2555  2838 D GpsLocationProvider: received SIM related action:
02-21 15:38:32.356  2555  2838 D GpsLocationProvider: SIM MCC/MNC is still not available
02-21 15:38:32.356  2555  2838 D GpsLocationProvider: received SIM related action:
02-21 15:38:32.361  2555  2838 D GpsLocationProvider: SIM MCC/MNC is still not available
02-21 15:38:32.689  2555  2838 D GpsLocationProvider: receive broadcast intent, action: android.intent.action.SIM_STATE_CHANGED
02-21 15:38:32.689  2555  2838 D GpsLocationProvider: received SIM related action:
02-21 15:38:32.698  2555  2838 D GpsLocationProvider: SIM MCC/MNC is still not available
02-21 15:38:32.699  2555  2838 D GpsLocationProvider: receive broadcast intent, action: android.intent.action.SIM_STATE_CHANGED
02-21 15:38:32.699  2555  2838 D GpsLocationProvider: received SIM related action:
02-21 15:38:32.704  2555  2838 D GpsLocationProvider: SIM MCC/MNC is still not available
02-21 15:38:32.704  2555  2838 D GpsLocationProvider: received SIM related action:
02-21 15:38:32.709  2555  2838 D GpsLocationProvider: SIM MCC/MNC is still not available
02-21 15:38:35.207  2555  2838 D GpsLocationProvider: setRequest ProviderRequest[ON interval=0]
02-21 15:38:35.214  2555  2838 D GpsLocationProvider: startNavigating, singleShot is false
02-21 15:38:35.214  2555  2838 D GpsLocationProvider: setting position_mode to standalone
02-21 15:38:35.214  2555  2838 V GpsLocationProvider: reportStatus status: 1
02-21 15:38:35.215  2555  2838 D GpsLocationProvider: setRequest ProviderRequest[OFF]
02-21 15:38:35.216  2555  2838 D GpsLocationProvider: stopNavigating
02-21 15:38:35.216  2555  2838 V GpsLocationProvider: reportStatus status: 2
02-21 15:38:35.218  2555  2838 D GpsLocationProvider: receive broadcast intent, action: android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE
02-21 15:38:35.223  2555  2838 D GpsLocationProvider: setRequest ProviderRequest[ON interval=0]
02-21 15:38:35.223  2555  2838 D GpsLocationProvider: startNavigating, singleShot is false
02-21 15:38:35.223  2555  2838 D GpsLocationProvider: setting position_mode to standalone
02-21 15:38:35.223  2555  2838 V GpsLocationProvider: reportStatus status: 1
02-21 15:38:35.237  2555  4243 D MARTIAN_ANDROID: 142.496 ZS location_cb
02-21 15:38:35.238  2555  4243 V GpsLocationProvider: reportLocation lat: XXXXXX long: XXXXXX timestamp: 1550759917000
02-21 15:38:35.238  2555  4243 D GpsLocationProvider: TTFF: 14
```